# Sections in tableView not showing

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have constructed the code below, however only 'Section 1' header plus elements are appearing. I would expect for all 3 headers to appear with their corresponding elements underneath, why is this not happening?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



class summary: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {


    var itemsInSections: Array<Array<String>> = [["1A", "1B", "1C"], ["2A", "2B"], ["3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E"]]
    var sections: Array<String> = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]



    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:TableViewCell1 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell1


        cell.label.text = "\(itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "tblcell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.itemsInSections[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.sections[section]
    }





}
```

Comment: Is `numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView)` even called? In the documentation, the signature is `optional func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int`, so I guess since you didn't implemented the correct one, it's returning 1 section by default.

Comment: Hey @Larme, you're totally right there, it wasn't being called. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `numberOfSection` signature is:

```
optional func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

If not set (since yours didn't match the signature), it should return 1 section by default. That's why you were seeing only one section.
Confirmed by you, your version wasn't called.

Answer (score 0):

replace this :-

```
  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
    }
```

with this :-

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                return self.sections.count

   }
```